In vueuse, what is the difference between isFetching and isFinished?
I'm using vueuse's UseFetch. What is the difference between isFetching and !isFinished ?
There definitely is a difference since some components crash using one rather than the other. Is it that the afterFetch function is called after isFetching and isFinished is set only after? Is there more documentation about it?

As detailed here and implied by the name

[isFetching] Indicates if the request is currently being fetched.

Useful if the request takes a long time and you want to put a loader of some sort to indicate it to the user. Particularly useful if they are on a slow connection.
The other one

[isFinished] Indicates if the fetch request has finished

They might mean the same thing but for quality of life, just have different names. But isFinished might come after an initial request, nothing should be there initially IMO. Also, in case of an error or a success of the HTTP call, isFinished might be true.

There is not much more documentation to that utility, but you could ask for any precisions on the Discord or the GitHub of the project.
Otherwise, why do you not use the useFecth baked into Nuxt3?


Is it that the afterFetch function is called after isFetching and isFinished is set only after?

Might be the case yes. Bind it to a button and call them, with a console.log and by inspecting the network request tab of your browser devtools, you might find all the answers that you still have right now.
I unfortunately do not know the exact behavior myself but you should have some errors to guide you too as to what's failing exactly.
